Conflict when using "Pressable" in "Scrollview" on iOS
With React Native, I use the ScrollView component and, inside it, Pressable components.
Often and exclusively on iOS, there seems to be a conflict since scrolling doesn't seem to work if the finger is placed on a Pressable element, as shown in the video :

Since the Pressable element is quite large, it degrades the user experience when scrolling (sometimes the element is even considered pressed and opens).
import React from 'react';

import {Pressable, ScrollView, View} from 'react-native';

const DashboardScreen = () => {
  return (
    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      <Pressable>
        <View>...</View>
      </Pressable>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default DashboardScreen;

Does anyone have an idea of how to limit the problem? Thanks a lot.
